# Google Calendar API freebusy query travel time

Tags: api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query to determine time slots available for scheduling. It looks like by default free busy query does not include travel time as booked time. Is there any workaround? Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. No mention of travel time in that API. You seem to be looking for [Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/):

> Retrieve duration and distance values based on the recommended route
>   between start and end points.

Comment: Not really. In the apple calendar, you can set a fixed time for travel like 1 hour or 30 minutes. Since I can set travel time with iOS apple calendar on the Google calendar and later see custom data with 3rd party app like Fantastical2 I'm pretty sure this data is stored in the event. metadata.